# Jsoup Url Redirect Not Getting destination url

Tags: redirect, jsoup

```
Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://yourparks.co.uk/parks/referral/2528").followRedirects(true).execute();
System.out.println(response.url());
```

I have tried to get the destination url using the above jsoup code but when i run it i get the same url.

Answer (score 1):

The server behind the url https://yourparks.co.uk/parks/referral/2528 doesn't send any HTTP redirect code (301, 302 etc).

This is why you get the "same url".

Comment: @webscrapingtech There's nothing to solve. The url isn't redirected.

Comment: when you click this url you are taken to another external url am looking for a way to extract that external url and store it in a string

Comment: The redirect is probably triggered by javascript, try htmlunit or an other headless browser with js support.